# How to stop showing exception when angular project timed out?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, timeout, nullreferenceexception

As you can see there is no debugger written here or any breakpoints given still it just haults execution here whenever Angular project get logged out due to timeout

[image: Image to describe the error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that was a silly one. I just unchecked the box of 'Break when this exception type is thrown'. From the next executions it's not getting haulted.